# Undesired behaviour of \parbox within figure environment

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, pstricks

I want to put a `\parbox` in a figure that is drawn by `pstricks`. The `pspicture` environment is inside of a `figure` environment. As an example:

```
\documentclass[singlecolumn, nofootinbib, notitlepage]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3) 
\rput[tl](-2, 2){\parbox{4cm}{I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. }}
\end{pspicture}

\label{some label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: example within figure-environment]

For some reason, the text within the `\parbox` is *not* justified, as it should be the case in a `\parbox`, but it is centered. However, if I do not put the `pspicture` environment in a `figure` environment, then the text in the `\parbox` *is* justified, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass[singlecolumn, nofootinbib, notitlepage]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3) 
\rput[tl](-2, 2){\parbox{4cm}{I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. }}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example without figure-environment]

How can I put a justified text in a `pspicture` that is inside of a `figure` environment? In other words, how do I have to modify the first example such that the text in the `\parbox` is justified (instead of centered)? If there is an alternative to `\parbox` that works (i.e. which is justified in this situation), I'm fine with that as well.

Comment: Hmmm.. Seems to have something to do with `revtex4-1` as it works fine with XeLaTeX if you use `\documentclass{article}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deep within the bowels of [`revtex4-1`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) it actually appends `\centering` to `\@parboxrestore` at the start of a float:

```
\appdef\@xfloat@prep{%
 \appdef\@parboxrestore{\centering}%
}%
```

`\@xfloat@prep` is a macro called to prepare some presets for the float environment.

This means that all `\parbox` constructs inside a float will be issued with `\centering`. The quickest way to avoid this would be to issue `\let\centering\relax` before using a `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}% http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1
\usepackage{pstricks}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3)
\rput[tl](-2, 2){\let\centering\relax\parbox{4cm}{I want this text to be justified. 
  I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this 
  text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. }}
\end{pspicture}
\label{some label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For a more global approach, just redefine `\@xfloat@prep` within your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat@prep{%
  \ltx@footnote@pop
  \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}%
  \def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}%
  \c@mpfootnote\z@
  \let\H@@footnotetext\H@@mpfootnotetext
}%
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

use a tabular instead of a `\parbox`

```
\rput[tl](-2, 2){\tabular{p{4cm}}I want this text to be justified. 
  I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this 
  text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be
  justified. 
\endtabular}
```